# Recorrer un Json 2 niveles con php

Tags: php, json

Estoy con un problema de lectura de un json "en dos niveles" con php.

```
{
"fechaTotalizacion": "Aug 28, 2021, 10:05:23 AM",
"estadoRecuento": {
    "mesasEsperadas": 7413,
    "mesasTotalizadas": 1250,
    "cantidadVotantes": 315080,
    "participacionPorcentaje": 72.86
},
"valoresTotalizadosPositivos": [
{
    "idAgrupacion": "10",
    "nombreAgrupacion": "Candidatura 10",
    "votos": 20580,
    "votosPorcentaje": 6.91,
    "listas": [
    {
        "idLista": "1",
        "nombreLista": "Lista 1",
        "votos": 20580
    }
]
},

{
    "idAgrupacion": "11",
    "nombreAgrupacion": "Candidatura 11",
    "votos": 18746,
    "votosPorcentaje": 6.29,
    "listas": [
    {
        "idLista": "3",
        "nombreLista": "Lista 3",
        "votos": 6280
    },
    {
        "idLista": "1",
        "nombreLista": "Lista 1",
        "votos": 6256
    },
    {
        "idLista": "2",
        "nombreLista": "Lista 2",
        "votos": 6210
    }
]
},
{
    "idAgrupacion": "13",
    "nombreAgrupacion": "Candidatura 13",
    "votos": 18462,
    "votosPorcentaje": 6.19,
    "listas": [
    {
        "idLista": "1",
        "nombreLista": "Lista 1",
        "votos": 9362
     },
     {
        "idLista": "2",
        "nombreLista": "Lista 2",
        "votos": 9100
     }
   ]
}
],
"valoresTotalizadosOtros": {
"votosNulos": 8738,
"votosEnBlanco": 14080,
"votosRecurridosComandoImpugnados": 8565,
"votosRecurridosComandoImpugnadosPorcentaje": 2.71
}
}
```

Accedo si problemas a "valoresTotalizadosPositivos" primer nivel con:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data->valoresTotalizadosPositivos);$i++){ 

    $idAgrupacion= $data->valoresTotalizadosPositivos[$i]->idAgrupacion;
    $cantidad = $data->valoresTotalizadosPositivos[$i]->votos;
    echo "id agrupa: ".$idAgrupacion."<br> votos: ".$cantidad;
    echo "<br><br>";
    
}
```

Cada Agrupación puede tener mas de una lista.
El tema es como recuperar los valores "listas" que pertenecen a esa Agrupación
Seria otro for dentro creería, pero no le encuentro la llegada al dato, no interpreto si es otro objeto o array...

Resultado a mostrar:

**id agrupación: 10** 
**votos:20580**

lista 1 = 20580 votos

**id agrupación: 11**
**votos: 18746**

lista 3 = 6280 votos
lista 1 = 6256 votos
lista 2 = 6210 votos
...

y asi sucesivamente con todas las agrupaciones que haya.

Mil gracias a quien me de una mano, entiéndase que soy novato en json
Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es como dices, la propiedad `listas` del JSON es un array, por tanto, debes leer los elementos del mismo abriendo un bucle interior. Algo así:

```
$items=count($data->valoresTotalizadosPositivos);      
for($i=0;$i<$items;$i++){   
    $idAgrupacion= $data->valoresTotalizadosPositivos[$i]->idAgrupacion;
    $cantidad = $data->valoresTotalizadosPositivos[$i]->votos;
    echo "id agrupa: ".$idAgrupacion."<br> votos: ".$cantidad;
    echo "<br><br>";
    foreach($data->valoresTotalizadosPositivos[$i]->listas as $lista) {
        echo "lista {$lista->idLista} = {$lista->votos} votos <br />";
    } 
}
```

NÓTESE que he creado una referencia al total de elementos una sola vez en la variable `$items`, es recomendable hacerlo cuando uses bucles `for`, pues si pones el `count` dentro del bucle, volverá a contar los elementos en cada iteracción, lo cual puede tener un impacto negativo en arrays u objetos con muchos elementos o en contextos donde la memoria es limitada. Esta práctica está indicada con toda claridad en el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.for.php):

> El código anterior puede ser lento, debido a que el tamaño del array
> se capta en cada iteración. Dado que el tamaño nunca cambia, el bucle
> puede ser fácilmente optimizado mediante el uso de una variable
> intermedia para almacenar el tamaño en lugar de llamar repetidamente a
> `count()`...

---

### Otra alternativa

Quizá una mejor manera de hacer lo que quieres sea usando `foreach`, el cual te permite escribir un código más limpio y no tienes que preocuparte en ningún caso por cuántos elementos tenga el array, cosa que sí debes hacer si usas `for`.

Y, para no recargar tanto el código, yo almacenaría todo en una sola variable (`$html` en este caso). Esto tiene la ventaja de que permite depurar con mayor rapidez, pues sólo tendrías que revisar tu variable de salida.

Así debería funcionar (oberva la nitidez/sencillez del código con respecto al bloque anterior):

```
$html="";
foreach($data->valoresTotalizadosPositivos as $valor) {
    $html.="id agrupa: {$valor->idAgrupacion} <br /> votos: {$valor->votos} <br /><br />";
    foreach($valor->listas as $lista) {
        $html.="lista {$lista->idLista} = {$lista->votos} votos <br />";
    }     
}
echo $html;
```